# Does any solution exist to use vim from touch screen?

Tags: input-devices

Actually, I hit this problem when I used ssh from my android phone to log in into a linux server, and I tried to use vim to edit some files.

It was a little bit... displeasing, although I could do everything which I could do from a normal desktop/keyboard.

*Extension:* There was a question, why it was displeasing if I could do anything I wanted. For example, typing `5j45|` on an emulated keyboard on a touchscreen has a *much* lower information rate (between your brain and your device) as touching the intended character position on a touchscreen.

Comment: I haven't used them so I don't know if either are suitable or quiality, but here are two Android apps which give some degree of vim control: [VimTouch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch) and [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside)

Comment: The main unknown for me with these tools is: is it easy/feasible to edit remote files through them, with netrw or otherwise?

Comment: The start might be using something like the Android "Hacker's Keyboard" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard as on screen keyboard. I can imagine more touch support, though (for placing cursor, scrolling, ...)

Comment: I use this kind of script on my Nokia N900: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3141

Comment: If you could do everything that you could do from a normal keyboard, what about it was displeasing? (I can think of several answers to this, but it would help to know which one(s) you're actually implying).

Comment: @Rich For example, typing `5j45|` on an emulated keyboard on a touchscreen has a *much* lower information rate (between your brain and your device) as touching the intended character position. On my opinion, a set of similar accelerations would be needed.

Comment: There are some activities for which a keyboard will always be a more suitable interface than a touch screen. Writing code is probably one of them. Other tasks that you use vi for might be more naturally done with another application when you're on a tablet.

Comment: BTW, thank you very much the correct answers - if anybody would convert them to answer, I were happy to accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does enabling mouse helps? This way you should be able at least do selections via touch. Maybe navigate files and buffers/tabs. Depends on plugins I guess.

```
set mouse=a
```

Comment: Wonderful! I think, it works only the client side terminal supports it, but it can work!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, modify the vim source event:

[image]

Comment: Welcome on the VIM SE! Could you please write more? It is not very clear for me on for the first spot, exactly what to do.

Comment: You may need this( 
 https://github.com/QQ1598058687/termux-vim-Touch-screen-version)