# What are some ways vim's interface could accommodate small-screen and touch-screen devices?

Tags: input-devices

First, I propose that this question be made into a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)--can a mod please do this.

Next, I'd like to keep answers focused on one of two related but distinct themes: (a) how vim translates to a device with a touch screen, and (b) how vim translates to a device with a *small* screen. I'd like completely to ignore a related issue (c) consisting of limitations imposed by particular mobile-device operating systems.

There are already some tools (some mentioned [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13/does-any-solution-exist-to-use-vim-from-touch-screen)) to bring vim to mobile devices, which typically *combine* ideas (a), (b), and (c); that is, they are efforts to make a small-screen, touch-screen vim on particular mobile platforms. However I think these efforts and answers sometimes miss the point because they conflate which of (a)/(b)/(c) are the issues they try to solve. Vim with a full external keyboard plugged into a jailbroken mobile device with a 4" screen would largely function like any other vim; no further changes would be needed except possibly some zoom feature unavailable in traditional vim.

So, I would like vim users to offer their thoughts on what particular adaptations could be made to vim to accommodate (a) touch screens, with on-screen keyboards, and (b) small screens (independent of whether the keyboard is on-screen or external).

For a simple example, an answer that seems appropriate regarding issue (a) would be:

> A major advantage of using vim with a separate keyboard is navigating with the `hjkl` keys, particularly because these keys are in the home row on a keyboard / are naturally where one's fingers rest when using a keyboard. Since on-screen keyboards do not have a natural resting point for the fingers, there is not an analogous advantage to navigating with keys in a particular row of the keyboard (though there may still be some advantage to navigating with keys all in the same row). Consequently, for a fully operational touch-screen vim to solve the document navigation problem as well as traditional vim, it would need a new paradigm for navigation. Since the natural resting stance for a touch screen is a finger over the screen, a potential navigation solution would be for directional finger motions over the screen to navigate in normal mode.

Now please note that I am not claiming that I have offered a correct or great answer in my example, but there are three points about this example that I want to emphasize:

1. It expresses a feature of traditional vim that is a major selling point for vim / a highly desirable feature.
2. It explains precisely why/how the touch-screen paradigm breaks this feature.
3. It proposes a workaround for touch-screens to recover this feature.

At the very least, components 1 and 2 are purely factual; while component 3 is subject to some debate, it is at least undebatable that the workaround *could* work, and ideally via community discussion some understanding of the most promising solutions could be discovered.

Comment: To make something community wiki, [edit] the post and click the checkbox on the right (between the markdown and the preview).

Comment: The vim_dev mailing list is the appropriate place for that kind of discussion.

Comment: I don't have the checkbox...is this edit only available to users above certain rep?

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) I cannot, as the asker of the question, do that conversion.

Comment: Vim already works well with small screens: 80x24 characters. As for touch screens, [this was asked before](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13/51).

Comment: Yes, if you read closely, you'll see I linked to that question in mine, and specifically explained what I found lacking about it / its answer.